# iOS app updating process

Tags: ios

Apologies if this has been asked before but I couldn't find anything specific to my situation..

I've been tasked with creating a new version of an app already on the market place.
Unfortunately, the client only has access to the binary and not the source code as the previous development team didn't provide this information.

The client has been unable to get in touch with the previous development team so I can assume getting a hold of the original source code is off the table.

I was wondering, in a case like this, how does the iOS upgrade procedure work?

As an additional question, is it possible for the new app to access the data stored by the old app and if so, can anyone point me in the right direction on how to go about doing this please?

Thank you!

Comment: All you need is access to the iTunesConnect account so you can submit the update and the app you write simply needs to use the same bundle id as the original app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the iTunes Connect account, with which this app was published the problem is not too large: you can update app with any binary that have the same application id (bundle identifier) and larger version number.

You definitely can have access to the data of previous version - either it's stored in NSUserDefaults or app Documents folder etc., but you should have a clue of its format (e.g. keys of NSUserDefaults) - some reverse engineering of binaries can help.

Comment: Reverse engineering of the existing binary might be just what I need.. are there any tools or tutorials you can suggest?

Comment: Sure, [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com) - is a great disassembler, you can try demo mode for free (sessions are limited to 30 minutes) or can buy full app. [There's a little tutorial](http://www.hopperapp.com/tutorial.html)  covering its features - I'm sure with decompiler you'll have a clue what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

To make the update you must have the same bundleIdentifier as the current version. This will be displayed in iTunes Connect.

To get the stored data, you should use a tool called iFunBox. 
Here's a little tutorial on how you can do it:

## Steps for using iFunBox

1. Download the current version of the app

   - You should also use the apps functions, so the app saves the data you wish to extract.
2. Connect your iDevice to your Mac/PC
3. Download and install iFunBox (link here: http://www.i-funbox.com)
4. Launch the program and navigate to your device
5. Press "User Applications", then your application
6. Find the data the app stores

   - The NSUserDefaults plist-file is located in "Library" -> "Preferences" and is called com.yourCompany.appName.plist
   - A lot of apps also stores files in yourApp/Documents/

You can also explore the apps folder and look for the data you need. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You must know the `bundleIdentifier` and use the same otherwise the apps wont update.
The version number must also be higher than the current one

Also the data saved in the old app can be read but you need to know in which format it is.